# How to add android:largeHeap = "true" in manifest file using Plugin.xml file in phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

How can we add android:largeHeap  to true in manifest file using plugin.xml file in android phonegap

Answer (score 14):

A solution that worked for us was doing this with a Cordova/PhoneGap Hook.

**Create a hook at the following path**

`{app-root}/hooks/after_prepare directory/010-update-android-manifest.js`

**Important to make this file executable**

`chmod +x 010-update-android-manifest.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs    = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var exec  = require('child_process').exec;
var path  = require('path');

var root = process.argv[2];
var androidManifest = path.join(root, 'platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml');
fs.exists(path.join(root, 'platforms/android'), function(exists) {
    if(!exists) return;
    fs.readFile(androidManifest, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;

        var lines = data.split('\n');
        var searchingFor = '<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"';
        var newManifest = [];
        var largeHeap = 'android:largeHeap="true"';
        lines.forEach(function(line) {
            if(line.trim().indexOf(searchingFor) != -1 && line.trim().indexOf(largeHeap) == -1) {
                newManifest.push(line.replace(/\>$/, ' ') + largeHeap + ">");
            } else {
                newManifest.push(line);
            }
        });

        fs.writeFileSync(androidManifest, newManifest.join('\n'));
    });
});
```

This will append **android:largeHeap="true"** to the application tag.

**Build your app**

`cordova build`

Comment: Thanks a lot.

To use this in Visual Studio 2015, I had to change "root" and remove "async" (which was not used anyway)


`var root = path.join(__dirname,"..");`


and in config.xml I added 
`<hook type="after_prepare" src="hooks/010-update-android-manifest.js" />` inside `<platform name="android">`

Just commenting cause I was lost how to add that myself.

Comment: way late to the party but: why cant u just add the android:largeHeap="true" attribute to the paltforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @IgorL. - the main reason is because the cordova build processes create the AndroidManifest.xml file.  Manual edits to that file get stepped on.

Comment: This helps a ton - thanks!  Quick note that later versions of cordova moved the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to `platforms/android/app/src/main`

Answer (score 2):

With Phonegap build you can use the following

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <application android:largeHeap="true"></application>
</gap:config-file>
```

This requires that you also add the android xmlnamespace to your widget element

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

(for more information see http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/)